# Build a message string depending on the type of signature of an invoice

Tags: java, design-patterns, comparative-review, formatting

The following method was meant to build a message depending on the type of signature of an invoice. It contains some if-else statements and code duplication.

The original method :

```
private String createSignatureMessage(InvoiceDTO invoiceDetails, int signatureType, Amount paid, Amount remaining) {
    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
    params.add(getCanal());
    if(signatureType == 1){
        params.add(invoiceDetails.getInvoiceId());
        // amount
        params.add(FormattingUtils.formatAmount(invoiceDetails.getTotalAmount()));
        params.add(Consts.EURO);
        params.add(invoiceDetails.getDate());
        // paid
        params.add(FormattingUtils.formatAmount(paid));
        params.add(Consts.EURO);
        // remaining
        params.add(FormattingUtils.formatAmount(remaining));
        params.add(Consts.EURO);
        return MessageFormat.format(InvoiceType.INS.equals(invoiceDetails.getType())?config.getPropertyStr("message.simple.signature.ins"):config.getPropertyStr("message.simple.signature"), params.toArray());
    } else if(signatureType == 2){
        params.add(invoiceDetails.getInvoiceId());
        // amount
        params.add(FormattingUtils.formatAmount(invoiceDetails.getTotalAmount()));
        params.add(Consts.EURO);
        params.add(invoiceDetails.getDate());
        return MessageFormat.format(InvoiceType.INS.equals(invoiceDetails.getType())?config.getPropertyStr("message.first.signature.ins"):config.getPropertyStr("message.first.signature"), params.toArray());
    } else if(signatureType == 3){
        params.add(invoiceDetails.getInvoiceId());
        // amount
        params.add(FormattingUtils.formatAmount(invoiceDetails.getTotalAmount()));
        params.add(Consts.EURO);
        params.add(invoiceDetails.getDate());
        // paid
        params.add(FormattingUtils.formatAmount(paid));
        params.add(Consts.EURO);
        // remaining
        params.add(FormattingUtils.formatAmount(remaining));
        params.add(Consts.EURO);
        return MessageFormat.format(InvoiceType.INS.equals(invoiceDetails.getType())?config.getPropertyStr("message.second.signature.ins"):config.getPropertyStr("message.second.signature"), params.toArray());
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

My attempt to refactor it using a command pattern :

```
interface Handler{
    String handle(InvoiceDTO invoiceDetails, Amount paid, Amount remaining);
}

private void addTotalAmount(InvoiceDTO invoiceDetails, List<Object> params) {
    params.add(invoiceDetails.getInvoiceId());
    params.add(FormattingUtils.formatAmount(invoiceDetails.getTotalAmount()));
    params.add(Consts.EURO);
    params.add(invoiceDetails.getDate());
}

private void addAmount(Amount amount, List<Object> params) {
    params.add(FormattingUtils.formatAmount(amount));
    params.add(Consts.EURO);
}

private void createMessageForLastSignature(List<Object> params, InvoiceDTO invoiceDetails, Amount paid, Amount remaining) {
    addTotalAmount(invoiceDetails, params);
    addAmount(paid, params);
    addAmount(remaining, params);
}

private String createSignatureMessage(InvoiceDTO invoiceDetails, int signatureType, Amount paid, Amount remaining) {
    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();
    params.add(getCanal());
    Map<Integer, Handler> commandMap = new HashMap<>();
    commandMap.put(1, (ordre, b, c) -> {
        createMessageForLastSignature(params, ordre, b, c);
        return MessageFormat.format(InvoiceType.INS.equals(invoiceDetails.getType())?config.getPropertyStr("message.simple.signature.ins"):config.getPropertyStr("message.simple.signature"), params.toArray());
    });
    commandMap.put(2, (ordre, b, c) -> {
        addTotalAmount(ordre, params);
        return MessageFormat.format(InvoiceType.INS.equals(invoiceDetails.getType())?config.getPropertyStr("message.first.signature.ins"):config.getPropertyStr("message.first.signature"), params.toArray());
    });
    commandMap.put(3, (ordre, b, c) -> {
        createMessageForLastSignature(params, ordre, b, c);
        return MessageFormat.format(InvoiceType.INS.equals(invoiceDetails.getType())?config.getPropertyStr("message.second.signature.ins"):config.getPropertyStr("message.second.signature"), params.toArray());
    });

    return commandMap.containsKey(signatureType) ? commandMap.get(signatureType).handle(invoiceDetails, paid, remaining) : "";
}
```

Can I have some feedback on the refactoring ?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Could you tell us what the `signatureType`s `1`, `2`, and `3` represent?

Answer (score 1):

It's going in the right direction. You are trying to extract common code and then each branch has in its own "callback" as implementation of your own interface (single method)!

As a functional approach, this seems quite good.

You can still split it more.

- `Message.format` is there 3 times. Make your interface return `List<Object>` rather than the final `String`. It also solves another small problem which is your `params` object being in the outer scope for your callbacks.
- Creation of your `commandMap` should be a separate method and possibly cached.
- Your lambda names :)

Another approach to consider is more object oriented where you create full implementation of your interface for each class. From cleanup code I see not much point, but from readability point of view it has some benefits. You create 3 classes, one for each implementation and you can name them so that it easily signals, what each implementations is for, and gives a better idea what it means when for example `signatureType` is 2. Also this `signatureType` can be another property of the interface and when you create map, you create your interface instances and associate them by this. `Message.format` can be possibly in parent abstract class.